# How to use Zapier with my Java RESTful API

Tags: java, rest, zapier

I've been asked to use Zapier to send SMS and add as a Subscriber to MailChimp once the addNewContact endpoint is called.

I've never worked with Zapier so I'm having trouble understanding how to proceed; in Zapier one can create an **App** or a **Zap**. Are they the same?

My task is to use Zapier for the purposes mentioned above, so if I could get some clarification/guidelines as to where to start and how to proceed it would be greatly appreciated.

We use `JAX-RS/Jersey 2.1`  so the main idea I have would be to call a REST API that belongs to Zapier with which I can make the request to send an SMS and add the newly created contact as a subscriber in MailChimp.

We previously created a Zap which triggered an SMS once the contact endpoint was called but this was done for a specific client, so this isn't the solution we're looking for since the authentication keys, clients and contact information will be dynamic.

My problem is that in the Zapier documentation I can't find anything related to my requirements, all I find is UI solutions directly working in zapier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, can you pls share the tutorial you referenced?

Answer (score 0):

A zap is the main interface in Zapier where you construct an integration between [available apps](https://zapier.com/app/explore) by setting up a trigger source to capture data, and subsequent actions to receive data.

An app is typically a branded service, and it's what you use within zaps to create your integration. Apps are provided by Zapier (you just need to authenticate within each service to use them) and you can also create your own apps.

There are also generic apps (like webhooks) that you can use to send data to an external service, such as your own REST API.

You can also send SMS directly within Zapier by using a [service like Twilio](https://zapier.com/zapbook/twilio/).